# Install Local Python Package with pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm building a python package to use for 'global' functions (i.e. stuff that I will use in multiple other projects). I have built the package using `py -m build` and it then puts the `MyPackage-0.1.0.tar.gz` into the `dist` directory in my folder.

My goal is to be able to run `pip install MyPackage` from within any other projects, and it will install the latest build of my package. In other words, I do not want to use something like `--find-links`. This way, I could also include the package in a `requirements.txt` file.

I have tried putting the tarball in a directory which is on my system's `PATH`, and into a subfolder within there (e.g. `PathDir/MyPackage/MyPackage-0.1.0.tar.gz`), but I keep getting the same 'No matching distribution found' error.

The documentation for `pip install` says:

> pip looks for packages in a number of places: on PyPI (if not disabled via --no-index), in the local filesystem, and in any additional repositories specified via --find-links or --index-url.

When it says 'in the local filesystem' where does it begin it's search? Is there a way to change this (e.g. set some environment variable)

Comment: Pip does not search the local file system, just as it does not search the package index. Either the package is right there on the top-level (the index, the local working directory, …) or not. If the package is in a non-standard location, you have to tell pip that explicitly.

Comment: FWIW, running a local package index might solve what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for files in the *local filesystem*, pip has no notion of search path. You must give a path accessible from the current working directory. It can be an absolute path:

```
pip install /path/to/MyPackage-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

a relative path:

```
cd /path
pip install to/MyPackage-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

or a simple name if the package file is inside the current working directory:

```
cd /path/to
pip install MyPackage-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after a lot of searching, and so here is the solution:

`pip` uses configuration files to define its internal settings. In these configuration files, you can specify default values for `find-links`. This means that python will look here for compatible packages, as well as online.

You can check what configurations have been set, and what files they will be searched in by running `pip config list -v`. You just need to edit/create one of the files listed and add your configuration as `pip.ini` with the following:

```
[install]
find-links=file://C:/Users/.../PathDir/MyPackage/
```

By creating this at the User/Global level (rather than the site level), this installation also works when inside a virtual environment.

Source: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

Answer (score -1):

`pip` can install from a source directory from the local filesystem if it's properly set up as a "packaging project". Starting from the [Python packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) example:

Imagine that you have a project with the following "canonical" layout:

```
example_project/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src/
│   └── example_package/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── example.py
└── tests/
```

then the following `pip` invocation will install your `example_package`:

`pip install path/to/example_project`

It reads the `pyproject.toml` file in the `example_project` directory and configures the installation accordingly.

As others pointed it out, there's no "search path" for `pip`. You have to tell it in which directory to look.

Comment: That's not actually addressing the situation of the question. They already have a build-able package and they have already built it; neither making the package build-able (it already is) nor installing it from source (they want to install from a pre-built tar-file) fits the question.

Comment: My purpose with this answer is to show that it's not necessary to go through the process of creating a source distribution tarfile and then installing from it. Installing a package with `pip` from a local source could be accomplished from the project directory "on the fly", so to speak. I agree that the OP's question focused on the "I already have a tarball, how to install from it" subproblem, but I think it could be useful to show _other_ visitors who landed on this page via Google that there's more than one way of installing a package from the local filesystem.

Answer (score -2):

`pip` can install packages from the local file system. They do not need to be even package files, they can be just working directories or git checkouts.

Usually I use `pip --editable`:

```bash
pip --editable /path/to/my/python/package
```

With `--editable` changes in `.py` files in the folder are automatically reflected to your application.

You can use `--editable` in `requirements.txt` file as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer OP's question "When it says 'in the local filesystem' where does it begin it's search?"

Comment: The package is already `build`, so `--editable` isn't of use for it.

Comment: Just pointing out there is no need to build the package in the first place